# Should I use history.js?

Tags: javascript, history.js, html5-history

I am working on dinamic web site it works fine with History API but I heard about some browsers issue about it.Which browsers support it?Then I decided to use history.js but it contains eval function and I know it is dangerous and slow.Shoul I use history.js or how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless you need to worry about supporting IE8 or earlier, or Opera Mini (at all) you should be fine with just the History API. Please see http://caniuse.com/#feat=history for more information.

In general, if you want to know if it's OK to use any browser APIs you'll find the answer on http://caniuse.com.

Comment: I'm afraid I have no idea. Does it matter? If this answers your question, would you mind marking it as the answer, please?

Comment: Yes.Of course.Would you give my question vote?

Comment: Thanks - there you go.

Comment: Thank you too.   :)

Comment: Why the downvote on the answer? I don't love it when people ask these kinds of questions but the answer is valid.